# Docker: download repository

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I need to download `docker` repository and first things first I try to execute

```
docker pull [OPTIONS] NAME[:TAG|@DIGEST]
```

After that I've got

```
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/images/create?fromImage=altinsky%2Fconvai&tag=deeppavlov: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Second things second I try to add myself to the group

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

There is no error after this command.
But when I try to check `docker`with

```
docker run hello-world
```

I've got again

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.37/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'
```

How can I fixed that?
Version of `ubuntu` - `Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS`

Comment: did you reboot the system after extended the remissions?

Comment: Are you sure that your `dockerd` daemon is running? If you're executing docker pull inside a container, for example, you should have run it with `--privileged` mode. If you're executing `docker pull` in your host, I'd check docker daemon is running.

Comment: does docker group is exist?

Comment: What does this output to you ? 
`sudo service docker status`. It seems you can't connect to the Docker socket, and it might be due to the fact that docker daemon is not running.
If you just added your user to the group, exit the shell and retry in a new one, it won't work just after adding the user to group.

Comment: @gcharbon `Active: active (running) since Ср 2018-07-11 10:35:56 MSK;`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor after restarting that's ok! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**adding docker group**

Adding `docker` group will do the trick, but don't forget to logout and login as permissions need to be flushed after you do `usermod` command, that was probably the step you have missed.

**sudo**

You can also run it using `sudo`.

Alternatevly you can permit yourself running docker privileged without typing password every time by editing `/etc/sudoers` using `visudo` command. Add a line like `your-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/docker/bin`, note to add it to the bottom or it might get overridden.

Comment: Adding yourself to the `docker` group is much safer and more ergonomical than requiring full root access for all Docker access.

Comment: @tripleee > Sudoers line presented above will do pretty much same as adding docker group to your user, except it will require you to type `sudo` in front with exception of not requiring password, it is not full root access, only superuser access when executing docker bin. I am pretty sure there is no difference between two, AFAIK anything you do with docker bin will have to go over docker.sock. I myself prefer adding docker group to to avoid having to type sudo.

Comment: "Superuser" is just an informal synonym for `root`. Going through `sudo` means if there is a bug in Docker you can obtain and keep root privileges, while being a member of the group executes everything as yourself, without any need to elevate privileges at any point. This also makes it easier to keep track of who did what on a multiuser system, and avoids having to make your private Docker files effectively both readable and writable by anyone else who uses Docker.

Comment: Sure, agreed, IMHO Docker is not something to be relied on security wise. I would rely on layers bellow it. @tripleee

Answer (score -1):

You should reboot the system after extended the remissions. Actually, logout/login is enough.

If it's not solved and services is running, just add perms for an all

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

or only for you

```
sudo chown $USER:docker /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Changing the owner and permissions of the socket is poor advice. You should make sure you are a member of the right group to access it, but beyond that, don't mess with it.